# Reduce Camel FTP Component Logging

Tags: java, logging, ftp, log4j, apache-camel

I am using the Camel FTP component (but I guess it doesn't matter specifically which one) and every 2 seconds I get a connected and logged in message in my log file, as below. I am using **log4j** and have it set to logging level to **info**.

*INFO  org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer  - Connected and logged in to:*

Is there a way to reduce the logging on this (or any) component, as I do not need this to be repeated every 2 seconds.

My ftp command now has `disconnect=true` added to stop the server closed connection message from appearing, but this has been replaced by the message above.

```
from("ftp://"+ftpLocation+"/?delete=true&initialDelay=5000&delay=2000&disconnect=true")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have configured log level to show INFO message it will show up in your logs..if you don't want the specific line to be printed just comment it in your FtpConsumer class.

Comment: I guess you completely remove the SFTP logging by tuning the log4J to not to log for org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer .

Comment: I would prefer to not turn off all FtpConsumer logging, although I cannot find this particular statement in my FtpConsumer class.

Comment: Yeah lets reduce that noise. I have logged a ticket - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8603 - A patch is much welcome.

Comment: Do you mind marking this as answered / closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has been answered by Claus Ibsen with a ticket raised [here](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8603).